# Android handler every second does not work

Tags: android, handler

I have handler in my MainActivity and it works perfectly fine at first but for some reason it suddenly doesn't work it did not repeat the method every second anymore.

```
  private void showElapsedTime() {
        SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("chronometer",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
        long elapsedMillis = (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - chronometer.getBase())/1000;

        editor.putLong("time",elapsedMillis);
        Log.d(TAG, "seconds"+elapsedMillis);
        editor.commit();
    }

 @Override
      protected void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
          firebaseauth.addAuthStateListener(authListener);
        mChildReference1.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
              @Override
              public void onDataChange (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
                    String status = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);

                   if (status.equals ("occupied")) {

                        chronometer.start();


                       handler1.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                           @Override
                           public void run() {
                               showElapsedTime();

                               handler1.postDelayed(this, 1000); //every seconds
                           }
                       },0);
        else

                  handler1.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);

              }
```

Comment: use CountDownTimer

Comment: Why you have call postDelayed 2 time

Comment: And why you have initiate it in ValueEventListener and remove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
private Handler handler = new Handler();
private Runnable runnable;

handler.postDelayed(runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);

        }
    }, 1000);
```

You need pass the same runnable object to the second handler inside run function.